# How can I spread a Vec<> into the arguments of format!()?

Tags: rust, formatting, string-formatting

I have a `Vec` of strings (`str` or `String`), and I would like to use them as the arguments for `format!()`. If the `...` syntax of JS was available, I'd do something like this:

```
let data = vec!["A", "B", "C"];
let result = format!("{} says hello to {} but not to {}", ...data);
```

Is there any alternative in Rust that would make something like this possible, and ideally without it being incredibly verbose?

I assume part of the difficulty is that the `Vec` might not have the right number of arguments, so it would be acceptable to me for it to panic if it has the wrong number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**dyn-fmt** crate](https://crates.io/crates/dyn-fmt/) looks like exactly what I need. It specifies a trait which adds a `format()` method to strings, which takes an Iterator. Any extra arguments are ignored, and missing ones are replaced with an empty string, so it won't panic. If you don't need `format!()`'s various formatting options, then it looks like a really good solid option.

```rust
use dyn_fmt::AsStrFormatExt;
let data = vec!["A", "B", "C"];
let result = "{} says hello to {} but not to {}".format(data);
assert_eq!(result, "A says hello to B but not to C");
```

Comment: How this differs from @Inline answer?

Comment: @Netwave Completely different crate, with an unfortunately similar name.

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no way to do that without writing much code by hand or using procedural macro to generate necessary code.

As a more simple workaround you may try to use [dynfmt](https://crates.io/crates/dynfmt), which provides way to pass arguments dynamically.

```rust
use dynfmt::{Format, SimpleCurlyFormat};

let formatted = SimpleCurlyFormat.format("{} says hello to {} but not to {}", &["A", "B", "C"]);
assert_eq!("A says hello to B but not to C", formatted.expect("formatting failed"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought producing a `Vec<String>` was wasteful in @Netwave's answer, so I improved it using `iter.flat_map()`:

```rust
fn flat_map_niave(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let data = vec!["A", "B", "C"];
    let separators = vec![" says hello to ", " but not to "];
    b.iter(|| {
        let mut phrases = separators.iter();
        data.iter()
            .intersperse_with(|| phrases.next().unwrap())
            .flat_map(|s| s.chars())
            .collect::<String>()
    });
}
```

There are various tricks to improve performance at the expense of readability, I'll leave these in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=480a2b032aa15a33b314a2aae79193fb).

- `flat_map_improved`: Use a `Vec<u8>` and `String::from_utf8()`
- `flat_map_unchecked`: Use a `Vec<u8>` and `String::from_utf8_unchecked()`

```
running 4 tests
test flat_map_improved  ... bench:         134 ns/iter (+/- 17)
test flat_map_niave     ... bench:         145 ns/iter (+/- 9)
test flat_map_unchecked ... bench:         116 ns/iter (+/- 6)
test vec_of_strings     ... bench:         235 ns/iter (+/- 6)
```

Comment: Cool answer man. Just read it. Btw, realized I didn't need the vec in the first place, it can be collected into a string directly. Would you mind updating the benchs? I feel curious :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot expand them as you would do in `js` or `python`.
But you can use `join` on a `Vec<String>` or `Vec<&str>`:

```rust
let data = vec!["A", "B", "C"];
let result = data.join("->");
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4c0bacf6c92744ec98028e60c0535a02)

As per **nightly** you could use [`intersperse_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.intersperse_with) and a combination of iterators:

```rust
    let data = vec!["A", "B", "C"];
    let phrases = vec![" says hello to ", " but not to "];
    let mut separators = phrases.iter().map(|x| x.to_string());
    let result = data
        .iter()
        .map(|x| x.to_string())
        .intersperse_with(|| separators.next().unwrap())
        .collect::<String>();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fb8f55ebb64750a572addf2d74af868b)

Comment: Sorry for the poor example, but the text between each argument may not always be the same. I've updated the question to give a proper example.